# What is the meaning of a "grey" tab in Safari?

Tags: macos, safari

[image: screenshot]

In Safari, sometimes a background tab will turn "grey". I have no idea what this means. It happens on my MacBook and my iPad. See the "index.html" tab in the screenshot.

Comment: Yeah… not a clue. Mine does it too, though I don't think I've spotted it happening recently. Maybe the new Safari 14.0.3 fixed it??

Comment: It happens on the most recent Safari, on Safari Technology Preview, on MacOS and on my iPad. So I doubt that it's bug.